Get data straight from query hook regardless of params sent
I have a table where all of the fetched data renders and I have different components that make api calls with different args (filters). How can I use query hooks to get any fetched data to render in that table regardless of parameters sent?
Now I am storing fetched data to a variable in global store and access it in the table with useSelector but I think there are some steps that could be avoided since I am double storing fetched data. (One comes with query, second I store manually with dispatch()).
Here's the example:
Here I get data from api and destructure refetch function to trigger fetch if query parameters change. Parameters are stored in Redux store.
const query = useSelector((state) => state.orderList.queryParams);

  const { refetch } = useGetOrderListQuery(query);

  useEffect(() => {
    refetch(query);
  }, [query, refetch]);

This hook is used in table component to show whether loading is happening const { isFetching } = useGetOrderListQuery(query);
As you can see I don't use data from query hooks. I set data manually inside useGetOrderListQuery.
getOrderList: builder.query({
      query: (arg) => ({
        url: ORDER_LIST,
        params: { ...arg },
      }),
      providesTags: ["Orders"],
      async onQueryStarted(_, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
        try {
    const { data } = await queryFulfilled;
    console.log(data);
    dispatch(setOrderData(data.results));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
      },
    }),

I believe I can avoid doing this      dispatch(setOrderData(data.results)); and access data right from the query but I don't see how.
Right now I am storing fetched data in the redux store but I think I can avoid it and get data from the query itsekf every time api call is made. The problem is that sometimes I need to pass different arg to query and I won't be able to get the same data.

The useQuery hook returns the fetched data, e.g. const { data, isFetching } = useGetOrderListQuery(query);, there's no need really to dispatch the results to be stored elsewhere in the store. Also, the useQuery hook automatically fetches when the query arg passed to it updates, the refetch function doesn't take any args, it only refetches the current query based on the last passed query args. If this isn't what you meant then please [edit] the post to clarify the problem.

Yep, you're taking extra steps in vain. Basically, you have 2 main approaches.
- Hooks
You can access the data directly from the hook:
OrdersScreen.tsx

const filters = useAppSelector(selectOrderFilters);

const { data: orderList, isLoading, refetch } = useGetOrderListQuery(filters, { 
  refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true 
});

<Flatlist 
  data={orderList}
  keyExtractor={(item) => String(item?.id)}
  renderItem={renderItem}
/>

- Selectors
In case you want to access the data directly from Redux and also w/o hooks you don't need to create a new Slice instead you can create custom selectors to access the cached data.
Let's say your apiSlice is called ordersApiSlice:
export const selectOrders = (state: RootState) => ordersApiSlice.endpoints.getOrderList.select(store.orderList.queryParams)(state);

// Usage: 
const orders = useAppSelector(selectOrders);

If you have to manage data before consuming it or something like that take in mind using createSelector().
